# rake aborted - is a directory/undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid3, dragonfly-gem

I've a rake task for importing pdf's from my filesystem into GridFS via dragonfly-gem. The task fails with no obvious reason.
I appreciate any help. Thanks!

The rake task:

```
task :worksafety_files => :environment do
# Importiert Archiv-Dateien via Dragonfly in GridFS  
Worksafety.all.each do |worksafety|
  if worksafety.doc_1_tmp != nil and File.exist?("#{Rails.root}/config/mongify/archiv/safety/#{worksafety.doc_1_tmp}")
    worksafety.doc_1 = File.new("#{Rails.root}/config/mongify/archiv/safety/#{worksafety.doc_1_tmp}")
    worksafety.doc_1_tmp = nil
  end
  if worksafety.doc_2_tmp != nil and File.exist?("#{Rails.root}/config/mongify/archiv/safety/#{worksafety.doc_2_tmp}")
    worksafety.doc_2 = File.new("#{Rails.root}/config/mongify/archiv/safety/#{worksafety.doc_2_tmp}")
    worksafety.doc_2_tmp = nil
  end
  if worksafety.doc_3_tmp != nil and File.exist?("#{Rails.root}/config/mongify/archiv/safety/#{worksafety.doc_3_tmp}")
    worksafety.doc_3 = File.new("#{Rails.root}/config/mongify/archiv/safety/#{worksafety.doc_3_tmp}")
    worksafety.doc_3_tmp = nil
  end
  if File.exist?("#{Rails.root}/config/mongify/archiv/safety/#{worksafety.doc_4_tmp}")
    worksafety.doc_4 = File.new("#{Rails.root}/config/mongify/archiv/safety/#{worksafety.doc_4_tmp}")
    worksafety.doc_4_tmp = nil
  end
  if File.exist?("#{Rails.root}/config/mongify/archiv/safety/#{worksafety.doc_5_tmp}")
    worksafety.doc_5 = File.new("#{Rails.root}/config/mongify/archiv/safety/#{worksafety.doc_5_tmp}")
    worksafety.doc_5_tmp = nil
  end       

  worksafety.save
end
end
```

Stacktrace:

```
rake aborted!
Is a directory - read
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems/dragonfly-08de999d19a0/lib/dragonfly/temp_object.rb:198:in `copy_to_tempfile'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems/dragonfly-08de999d19a0/lib/dragonfly/temp_object.rb:100:in `tempfile'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems/dragonfly-08de999d19a0/lib/dragonfly/temp_object.rb:107:in `file'
....
```

I've double checked the folder "safety". There are just pdf files in it (mime-tpye checked with file -i *). I think the issue is related to dragonfly, because when imagemagick is avtivated in the dragonfly config..

```
app.configure_with(:imagemagick)
```

the stacktrace is different:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems/dragonfly-       08de999d19a0/lib/dragonfly/image_magick/utils.rb:26:in `identify'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems/dragonfly-08de999d19a0/lib/dragonfly/image_magick/analyser.rb:44:in `format'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems/dragonfly-08de999d19a0/lib/dragonfly/function_manager.rb:39:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems/dragonfly-08de999d19a0/lib/dragonfly/function_manager.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in call_last'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems/dragonfly-08de999d19a0/lib/dragonfly/function_manager.rb:38:in `catch'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems/dragonfly-08de999d19a0/lib/dragonfly/function_manager.rb:38:in `block in call_last'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems/dragonfly-08de999d19a0/lib/dragonfly/function_manager.rb:37:in `each'
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broken regex look like check [here](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/issues/195)

because of which [this](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/blob/master/lib/dragonfly/image_magick/utils.rb#L24) piece of ur code

i.e `format, width, height, depth` all are set to `nil` because `scan` is returning `nil` because of broken `regex`

fix the `regex` from your side is what I suggest until they fix it and patch it

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, this helps. It's depends on the version of "identify" from imagemagick. The command output is different in each version.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error while using a rake task to import images based on a column in an excel document. Took me a few minutes to realize that if the file name field was blank this would be the resulting error.

I hope that helps someone :)